# Defining a threshold using aggregate data

Tags: meta-analysis, threshold

I hoped for some advice - sorry if this is a very daft quesion.

I have aggregate data on a medical test taken in both healthy people & patients with disease.

The test provides a result on a scale from 0-100. There is no defined threshold for classifying people as healthy/diseased yet but (as shown below) there is a consistent difference between healthy & disease people....

[image]

Is it possible to estimate the likelihood of having disease at given values, using this aggregate data?  If so, how would this best be done?

Thank you so much and sorry if this is a stupid question

[image: kdens - exploring thresholds]